# How to Fix mySQL ETL query with multiple if/then scenarios based on statuses in a log table (Joins, Duplicates, and more Fun!)

Tags: mysql

Table: etl_transformed - This table holds cleaned data

```
id, inactive, hooks_log_headers_id, hooks_log_headers_client_id, hooks_log_headers_promotion_id, email_address, timestamp, status, status_message, old_value, new_value
'22', '0', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '2023-05-08 11:22:36', '1', 'success', 'old data', 'new data'
'23', '0', '652', '5001', '3', '2@test.com', '2023-05-08 11:22:36', '1', 'success', 'old data', 'new data'
'24', '0', '655', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '2023-05-08 11:22:36', '1', 'success', 'old data', 'new data'
```

Table: etl_load_log - This table is a log I write when I post the new data from the etl_transformed table to an API. Each attempt is logged as a single row.

```
id, inactive, etl_transformed_id, hooks_log_headers_id, hooks_log_headers_client_id, hooks_log_headers_promotion_id, email_address, attempt_number, start_time, end_time, duration, status, status_message, user_id, comments
'1', '0', '22', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '1', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '1', 'pending', '0', ''
'2', '0', '22', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '2', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'3', '0', '22', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '3', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'4', '1', '22', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '4', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'5', '1', '22', '651', '5001', '3', '1@test.com', '5', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '00:00:00', '2', 'success', '0', ''
'21', '0', '24', '651', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '1', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '1', 'pending', '0', ''
'22', '0', '24', '651', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '2', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'23', '0', '24', '651', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '3', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '2023-05-08 11:45:05', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'24', '1', '24', '651', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '4', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '00:00:00', '3', 'error', '0', ''
'25', '0', '24', '651', '5001', '3', '3@test.com', '5', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '2023-05-08 11:45:06', '00:00:00', '2', 'success', '0', ''
```

I am trying to write a query to select which posts to send to API. I want to post all of the data in the etl_transformed table to the API. Each time I post to the API I write a new row in etl_load_log file with a status of 1 = pending, 2 = success, or 3 = error. I will use this query to choose which records in the etl_transformed table are to be sent to the API. I will send from the etl_transformed table if:

1. Step 1. If there are no records in the etl_load_log with a matching etl_transformed_id
2. Step 2. There is no mating record in the etl_load_log with a status of 1 or 2 (pending or success), and
3. Step 3. There are less than 3 records with a status = 3 EXCEPT if there is any matching record in the etl_load_log table with a status of 1 or 2 (I want to retry errors 3 times unless there is one or more pending or success records in the etl_load_log table. I only want to successfully send data 1 time to the API and retry any errors up to 3 times, then I will stop retrying to repost if there was no success and 3 errors.
4. Step 4. I also ignore rows in both tables that are marked as inactive = 1

Below is my current query, it works on steps 1, 2 and 4 above, and it will work when there is less than 3 records with a status = 3, but this is where it fails, because it will still display the error records when there are less thant 3 error records even if there is a matching record with a status of 1 or 2.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM etl_transformed t1
LEFT JOIN etl_load_log t2 ON t1.id = t2.etl_transformed_id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
    OR (t1.inactive = 0
        AND t2.inactive = 0 
            AND t2.status NOT IN (0, 1)
            AND ( 
                SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM etl_load_log 
                WHERE etl_transformed_id = t1.id 
                    AND inactive = 0
                    AND status = 2
                ) < 3
        )
ORDER BY t1.id ASC
;
```

I am also open to changing my schema and simplifying if necessary.